# What is Synology's RAID Technology based on?

Tags: network-attached-storage, linux-kernel, synology

I am curious about Synology's RAID Technology is based on which linux kernel modules.
It seems MD+LVM according to its service center but I am not quite sure. Or the RAID function on filesystem is also possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They use MDRAID+LVM and they use their proprietary software RAID implementation. Second one should be avoided due to smaller user base and recovery issues.

https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Storage/What_is_Synology_Hybrid_RAID_SHR

Comment: Actually I was confused and still confused now. I quote a sentence, SHR is based on a Linux RAID management system, from the post. It seems SHR is a managment application but eventually it still relies on linux kernel software RAID.

Comment: It’s a fork-out. Standalone quite poorly maintained code and some custom on-disk format.

Comment: It is weird, isn't? Just a hype or something else? But thank you anyway.

Comment: An attempt to punch above their weight IMHO.

Comment: The SHR is a mix of LVM and btrfs :https://daltondur.st/syno_btrfs_1/